# How to use a scanner to return a line from text file if line contains scanner input?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am wanting to store a line from a text file depending on if the input from a scanner is contained within the line of text.

However, the code below accepts all form of input, regardless of if the input is contained in the text file, so I am assuming the if else statement is completely ignored. I am unsure on how to fix this so any advice is appreciated.

```
Scanner editScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String editScannerInput = editScanner.nextLine();
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("src/FilmInfo.dat"));
String fileScannerLine = fileScanner.nextLine();


while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    if (fileScannerLine.contains(editScannerInput.toLowerCase())) {
        String chosenFilm = fileScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(chosenFilm);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Film name is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you printed out editScannerInput to make sure you aren't getting an empty string?

Comment: Printing editScannerInput outside the while loop gives me my input but inside the loop, the printed input is empty

Comment: I added a missing `}` on the while considering it wouldn't compile without it as written and that's not your problem. Feel free to re-edit if needed.

Comment: Edited to add the missing bracket

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, one issue with your code is that you never update the fileScannerLine variable as you are looping. Here is a working code snippet (with some minor modifications):

```
System.out.print("Enter input: ");
Scanner editScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String editScannerInput = editScanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("src/FilmInfo.dat"));

while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(editScannerInput.toLowerCase())) {
        String chosenFilm = line;
        System.out.println(chosenFilm);
    } else {
        System.out.println(String.format("The film '%s' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.", line));
    }
}
editScanner.close();
fileScanner.close();
```

Contrived test file:

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
111
222
333
```

Output:

```
1
The film '2' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.
The film '3' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.
11
The film '22' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.
The film '33' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.
111
The film '222' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.
The film '333' is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.
```

This solution will loop through all lines of your file and print out each match. If you're looking for one match or to store all matches in a list, the code can be easily modified to do so.

Comment: Implementing your changes always enforces the else statement of the if else statement

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can see by looking at my output that that is not the case.

Comment: I mean as in I don't get the output that you're getting, as in I get no output at all

Comment: More so, all input is regarded as incorrect, therefore displaying the contents of the else statement

Comment: You must have a mistake in your code then, as what I have works. The code is very simple; Within the loop it reads a line from a file and checks if it contains your input. Do some debugging by printing the contents of the line and editScannerInput variables.